# C++ GDB Python Pretty Printing Tutorial?

Tags: c++, python, gdb

I am looking for a solid tutorial on creating a custom printer.

There are a few sparse pages on the GDB page however they are far from complete and leave much to the imagination!

For instance, I'd love to be able to create a PrettyPrinter for our custom shared pointer class.

Comment: You mean these http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html#Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter?

Comment: yes those leave much up to the imagination of implementing pretty printers for complex structures for instance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check out Tom Tromey's pretty printing tutorials [part 1](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524) and [part 2](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=546). There is also the [libstdc++-v6 pretty printer implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py;hb=HEAD) to look at, which is what I used myself as a template when I started out. A somewhat simpler example (as of this writing) is the [Boost pretty printer](https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer/blob/master/boost/printers.py) by [Rüdiger Sonderfeld](https://github.com/ruediger).

Answer (score 16):

This one looks interesting for starters:
[Python Pretty-Printers from redhat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/debuggingprettyprinters.html)

From this simple tutorial, you can proceed to more advanced ones. 
Here is a good example:[Pretty-printers for libstc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py;hb=HEAD)